# Can't handle submit function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, onclick, submit

I want to show error message with Viewbag but i can't handle button click function. I couldn't 
find the reason. My aim is to show my viewbag message if it isn't null.

In view:

```
  $(function () {        
            $("#changecompanyuserinfobutton").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var deneme = ViewBag.MessageForAllRes;
                if(deneme != null)
                alert(deneme);            
            });
        });

 <button type="submit" id="#changecompanyuserinfobutton">ChangeCompanyUserInfoValues</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove hash(#) from your id in the html and see it works.

```
<button type="submit" id="changecompanyuserinfobutton">ChangeCompanyUserInfoValues</button>
```

Comment: It was just texting mistake. In my project ir is without # but still not working

Comment: there might be a conflict, use jQuery.noConflict();

Answer (score 0):

remove  `e.preventDefault();`. it is prevented your submit  action.
your action is calling.check, before pur alert message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use submit event handler with form ID. Check the syntax when you access ViewBag data inside javascript.

```
<form id="target" >
 <button type="submit" id="changecompanyuserinfobutton">ChangeCompanyUserInfoValues</button>
</form>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#target").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var deneme = "@(ViewBag.MessageForAllRes)";
            if (deneme != null)
                alert(deneme);
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you want to use button ID then you can use [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event.

```
<button type="submit" id="changecompanyuserinfobutton">ChangeCompanyUserInfoValues</button>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#changecompanyuserinfobutton").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var deneme = "@(ViewBag.MessageForAllRes)";
            if (deneme != null)
                alert(deneme);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Submit with formid is working for second click not for first one

Comment: Both should work, check these samples;
(1) http://jsfiddle.net/NLJBd/, (2) http://jsfiddle.net/puGfp/

Comment: maybe it's related with form because it is not working on first click

Comment: OK, hope my answer helped you!